# Can't parser DOM from Facebook Groups

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

I crawling data from group facebook, this is example: https://www.facebook.com/groups/piandhust. I found element in inspect but when parser by css selecter in console cannot find element. I found the element:

```html
<span id="jsc_c_h9"><span class="xh99ass"><span><span class="x1i1rx1s x10l6tqk x10wlt62 x6ikm8r xjm9jq1 xzpqnlu">&nbsp;</span><span aria-hidden="true"> · </span></span></span><span class="x1kgmq87 x3nfvp2"><span class="x3nfvp2"><span class=""><span><div class="x1rg5ohu"><span><span><div class="x6s0dn4 x1lcm9me x1yr5g0i xrt01vj x10y3i5r x3nfvp2 x1qx5ct2 x150jy0e x1e558r4 x1hr4nm9"><span class="x193iq5w xeuugli x13faqbe x1vvkbs x10flsy6 x1nxh6w3 x1sibtaa xo1l8bm x1qq9wsj"><span class="x1lliihq x6ikm8r x10wlt62 x1n2onr6 xlyipyv xuxw1ft">Quản trị viên</span></span></div></span></span></div></span></span></span></span><span class="xh99ass"><span><span class="x1i1rx1s x10l6tqk x10wlt62 x6ikm8r xjm9jq1 xzpqnlu">&nbsp;</span><span aria-hidden="true"> · </span></span></span><span><span class="x4k7w5x x1h91t0o x1h9r5lt x1jfb8zj xv2umb2 x1beo9mf xaigb6o x12ejxvf x3igimt xarpa2k xedcshv x1lytzrv x1t2pt76 x7ja8zs x1qrby5j"><a class="x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz x1heor9g xt0b8zv xo1l8bm" href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/piandhust/posts/5318367518191815/?__cft__[0]=AZUlyW9MRthrF5gJo5GU87rFsxuKUYOn7CUucL6-gNjmAI-6pMbqstyJcja6agx27D0D_sZC8s9o-KRJjI5ZOoT1uPMTANegrouKT1hDkzJKmFz47LJqMD1fmFm6b-FfpHq8HmP7ZZa2Yf0SptfQA0HxxBG2Rbna4ttRtT-yqii75hOMxyydmFYU-_0A34YR0lY&amp;__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R" role="link" tabindex="0"><span><span class="x16dsc37 x10wlt62 x6ikm8r x1rg5ohu xt0b8zv" aria-labelledby="jsc_c_hg"><div><div class="x15bjb6t x1qlqyl8 xjb2p0i xt0psk2 x9f619"><div class="x15bjb6t x1qlqyl8 xjb2p0i xt0psk2 x9f619"><svg style="height: 14px; margin-right: -75.0852px; overflow: visible; width: 135.909px;"><use xlink:href="#gid35" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use></svg></div></div></div></span></span></a></span></span><span class="xh99ass"><span><span class="x1i1rx1s x10l6tqk x10wlt62 x6ikm8r xjm9jq1 xzpqnlu">&nbsp;</span><span aria-hidden="true"> · </span></span></span><span class="xuxw1ft"><span class="x4k7w5x x1h91t0o x1h9r5lt x1jfb8zj xv2umb2 x1beo9mf xaigb6o x12ejxvf x3igimt xarpa2k xedcshv x1lytzrv x1t2pt76 x7ja8zs x1qrby5j"><span class="x1rg5ohu x1n2onr6 xs7f9wi"><svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="1em" height="1em" class="x1lliihq x1k90msu x2h7rmj x1qfuztq xcza8v6 x1kpxq89 xsmyaan" title="Đã chia sẻ với Nhóm công khai"><title>Đã chia sẻ với Nhóm công khai</title><g fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-448 -544)"><g><path d="M109.5 408.5c0 3.23-2.04 5.983-4.903 7.036l.07-.036c1.167-1 1.814-2.967 2-3.834.214-1 .303-1.3-.5-1.96-.31-.253-.677-.196-1.04-.476-.246-.19-.356-.59-.606-.73-.594-.337-1.107.11-1.954.223a2.666 2.666 0 0 1-1.15-.123c-.007 0-.007 0-.013-.004l-.083-.03c-.164-.082-.077-.206.006-.36h-.006c.086-.17.086-.376-.05-.529-.19-.214-.54-.214-.804-.224-.106-.003-.21 0-.313.004l-.003-.004c-.04 0-.084.004-.124.004h-.037c-.323.007-.666-.034-.893-.314-.263-.353-.29-.733.097-1.09.28-.26.863-.8 1.807-.22.603.37 1.166.667 1.666.5.33-.11.48-.303.094-.87a1.128 1.128 0 0 1-.214-.73c.067-.776.687-.84 1.164-1.2.466-.356.68-.943.546-1.457-.106-.413-.51-.873-1.28-1.01a7.49 7.49 0 0 1 6.524 7.434" transform="translate(354 143.5)"></path><path d="M104.107 415.696A7.498 7.498 0 0 1 94.5 408.5a7.48 7.48 0 0 1 3.407-6.283 5.474 5.474 0 0 0-1.653 2.334c-.753 2.217-.217 4.075 2.29 4.075.833 0 1.4.561 1.333 2.375-.013.403.52 1.78 2.45 1.89.7.04 1.184 1.053 1.33 1.74.06.29.127.65.257.97a.174.174 0 0 0 .193.096" transform="translate(354 143.5)"></path><path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M110 408.5a8 8 0 1 1-16 0 8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-1 0a7 7 0 1 0-14 0 7 7 0 0 0 14 0z" transform="translate(354 143.5)"></path></g></g></svg></span></span></span></span>
```

But when I parse them with css selector, the id "jsc_c_h9" contains link `https://www.facebook.com/groups/piandhust/posts/5318367518191815/?__cft__[0]=AZUlyW9MRthrF5gJo5GU87rFsxuKUYOn7CUucL6-gNjmAI-6pMbqstyJcja6agx27D0D_sZC8s9o-KRJjI5ZOoT1uPMTANegrouKT1hDkzJKmFz47LJqMD1fmFm6b-FfpHq8HmP7ZZa2Yf0SptfQA0HxxBG2Rbna4ttRtT-yqii75hOMxyydmFYU-_0A34YR0lY&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R` return null, below is my code:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("span[id*=jsc] > span > span > a")).map(item => item.getAttribute("href"))
```

And this result:

```
0: "https://www.facebook.com/groups/piandhust/posts/6026797134015513/?__cft__[0]=AZVIXUhI6uyrBKazYNkEB1flExYULdqOrWzY_X_ymK3lhQrVdmUJYfX-IrlxtZH3CyMhf3uTyQS87ZBbfdrYPw0pHFACcRMZtiIqaSX35y1pZ-5h267R2-YyesKEGtKcZ0Y05Ueo3hJHZW2fVKCTzXH0xgcvqNXrkiaCjI3gNkWTsRVXFM97LmzxDcuRbJSmyXJpib24QsAyRG-0DfkcMH1l&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R"
1: "https://www.facebook.com/groups/piandhust/posts/6026459217382638/?__cft__[0]=AZX0gcLTqwp7wu9WZE1xKVeL1gg3ozIrA1MMCza05EzGqe3C0GX3oEDxYiCLRmU9tUf7PNDb3Q1rdU8NsPp6L0-JTxGoPDPIFs0o2i8X3e5HNZLEFXCT8sUTZRUiyKTBSAmVi6qpNbCIDaJMzFXbTfrje_dqDO3uwrG40GYmhkbtHNmoetI_mVS36oZQxp2pEsM&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R"
2: "#"
3: "#"
4: "https://www.facebook.com/groups/piandhust/posts/5537096599652238/?__cft__[0]=AZW03TihoA87-WrggKKW7XFvzgzp1DgTTB2vayScGKHOTaadZal01CP7meYTR7CC8oS68vA1FxscIQ6574YSsPZEthwi313fKvzAkTfD2KHoBfByt3jaPHit2PslRg4XfmyXEz0P8jnfmqSmaicp5XxCL2Q2YflH8T9Ek0nVg1sp_6qyUxsaUGrRrQqt4_2b_JM&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R"
5: "#"
6: "#"
7: "#"
8: "https://www.facebook.com/groups/piandhust/posts/5337405762954657/?__cft__[0]=AZWU6V_tqhJ_88NA26YatCdo6qXB0Zsbu0vy8oRxEQIBv0B5E2LsznIcfTVXie3fclzL9L4U4XSIiuxcjMop7gtgalAhsU2BLnm3vJbhSukF8hHWaFp1BrbYYuXfaS5H-ELhPAEQkzWMOZ8U6K_Es4PD9adGFJvsh2Kz-DPLoxQH3aoyct-eXLnexXy9jpHjo6A&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R"
9: "https://www.facebook.com/groups/piandhust/posts/5318385338190033/?__cft__[0]=AZVNH1FPZFrw-NDAlA8xM04GmDAxKfUr-UlKJ8GFuUbLpga3tuChOhBlHxxxro5Ps6fu3LuJob-ZHWgUVQ_cePdIHnCf-VxinDEYvyGe0cUOahQdakaIzlqdZ9GrC9bBzaQYeCkINWjOATsv9Ng9IndcN4koOolXUFrCOvadcbxcEvYTNpUXJZp_NvR2U74IhLcH0D9JicT7zk8Plc42OOVm1_YSy6OYBQBXLkjxLujKLA&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R"
10: "#"
11: "#"
12: "#"
13: "#"
14: "#"
15: "#"
16: "#"
17: "#"
18: "#"
```

I don't know why, can you help me solve it? Thank you very much!

Comment: that's so weird, the HTML you posted has a single `a` element with no `id` yet the code seems to produce 19 outputs, all of them with an `id`

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them? Just so you don't get surprised when you get banned.